# PostgreSql jsonb field to view

Tags: postgresql, jsonb

I have this kind of jsonb data in one of column named "FORM" in a my table "process" and I want to create view with some data which are inside of row named field I just want name and value form field named array in this jsonb.

**here the jsonb:**

```
 {
      "column": [
        {
          "row": {
            "id": "ebc7afddad474aee8f82930b6dc328fe",
            "name": "Details",
            "field": [
              {
                "name": {
                  "id": "50a5613e97e04cb5b8d32afa8a9975d1",
                  "label": "name"
                },
                "value": {
                  "stringValue": "yhfghg"
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        {
          "row": {
            "id": "5b7471413cbc44c1a39895020bf2ec58",
            "name": "leave details",
            "field": [
              {
                "name": {
                  "id": "bb127e8284c84692aa217539c4312394",
                  "label": "date"
                },
                "value": {
                  "dateValue": 1549065600
                }
              },
              {
                "name": {
                  "id": "33b2c5d1a968481d9d5e386db487de52",
                  "label": "days",
                  "options": {
                    "allowedValues": [
                      {
                        "item": "1"
                      },
                      {
                        "item": "2"
                      },
                      {
                        "item": "3"
                      },
                      {
                        "item": "4"
                      },
                      {
                        "item": "5"
                      }
                    ]
                  },
                  "defaultValue": {
                    "radioButtonValue": "1"
                  }
                },
                "value": {
                  "radioButtonValue": "3"
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
```

and i want to this kind of jsonb in view data comes from subarray called field inside the object named row......

```
[
  {
    "name": {
      "id": "50a5613e97e04cb5b8d32afa8a9975d1"
    },
    "value": {
      "stringValue": "yhfghg"
    }
  },
  {
    "name": {
      "id": "bb127e8284c84692aa217539c4312394"
    },
    "value": {
      "dateValue": 1549065600
    }
  },
  {
    "name": {
      "id": "33b2c5d1a968481d9d5e386db487de52"
    },
    "value": {
      "radioButtonValue": "3"
    }
  }
]
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used `jsonb_array_elements` twice to expand the two arrays, then used `json_build_object` to make the result structure and `jsonb_agg` combine the several rows generated above into a single JSONB array.

I included a row number is the results so I could later apply `group by` so that results from several "process" rows would not be accidentally combined by the `jsonb_agg`.

```
with cols  as (select jsonb_array_elements( "FORM" ->'column') as r
                     ,row_number() over () as n from  "process" )
    ,cols2 as (select jsonb_array_elements(r->'row'->'field') as v
                     ,n from cols)
select jsonb_agg(json_build_object('name',v->'id','value',v->'value'))
from cols2 group by n;
```